# Relationships of orthogonal subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm struggling with the following problem:

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be supspaces of $V$. What is the relation between $(U_1+U_2)^\perp$ and $U_1^\perp \cap U_2^\perp$; and between $(U_1 \cap U_2)^\perp$ and $U_1^\perp + U_2^\perp$?

I would say that if $U_1^\perp = U_2$ then $U_1+U_2=V$, so $(U_1+U_2)^\perp=0$ and $U_1^\perp \cap U_2^\perp=\{0\}$. Then also $(U_1 \cap U_2)^\perp=V$ and $U_1^\perp + U_2^\perp=U_2+U_1=V$.

But here I put a lot of emphasis on the orthogonality of the subspaces. You think there is anything else interesting to see here?
Thanks a lot!

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $(U_1+U_2)^\perp=U_1^\perp \cap U_2^\perp$;

$(U_1 \cap U_2)^\perp=U_1^\perp + U_2^\perp$

First,try to prove that if $A,B$ are subspaces of $V$ and $A \subseteq B$ then $B^\perp \subseteq A^\perp$

Comment: Ok, so can I simply say that $(U_1+U_2)=V-(U_1^\perp \cap U_2^\perp)$ or $(U_1+U_2)^\perp=U_1^\perp \cap U_2^\perp$?

Comment: Okay, I think I got the second part as well. I made some sketches but I'm not sure if I could come up with the solution purely analytically. Any hints on what I should have a look at? Thanks a lot: $U_1 \cap U_2=V-U_1^\perp -U_2^\perp$ or $(U_1 \cap U_2)^\perp=U_1^\perp + U_2^\perp$